# DTS_E_InducedTransformFailureOnError when running SSIS package in another environment

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package which runs fine in the development environment, but after deploying to and running in the QA environment, it's returning a

> Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The 'component 'SAS...' failed because error code 0x80004002 occurred, and the error row...

I've compared the tables on the dev SQL server with those on the QA sql server, and both appear to match, so I'm not sure what's causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Either your environment or your data likely differs in QA.

If it is the environment, there is a .NET framework version issue discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/9169fd30-0057-4a01-a33e-04db7017e9dd/), for which a hotfix is available [here](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=969845).

There is a separate data-dependent issue discussed [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14044/ssis-sql-server-2008-errors).